# How to read the partitioning columns of spark stream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark streaming job where I am streaming the data and partitioning it by a single or multiple columns and storing in the gcs bucket. Below is the sample code where I am partitioning it by team and stored in gcs bucket.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext


temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "team1",100),
    (1, "team2",200),
    (2, "team3",300),
    (3, "team4",400)
], ["id", "team", "count"])

temp.writeStream.format('parquet').outputMode('append').option('path','gs://').partitionBy('team').start()
```

While reading the stream from the gcs bucket, I am not getting the "team" column back

```
df = spark.readStream.option('basePath','gs://').json('path')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't have a streaming dataframe in the code shown. Just use write and read functions, directly.

You only need to read the base path. Partitions will be automatically discovered.

Also, don't use `json()` to read Parquet data.